# SSH login without password

Tags: ssh, passwords, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up SSH so I don’t have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

You don't want to type your password when you ssh into a machine.  What can you use to accomplish this?  Are there any security concerns with your approach?

Comment: Why don't I want to type my password again?

Comment: What OSs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pair of SSH keys, placing a private key on the server and a public key on the client.  This will allow the client to connect to the server using it's public key instead of having to enter a password.

[SSH public key tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

Comment: is there any security concerns about this?

Comment: crst53: public/private key exchange is much more secure than using passwords, and much less likely to suffer from brute force attack on the SSH server. The problem is if you don't use a pass-phrase on the key anyone getting physical access to your machine may be able to login through your machine IIUC.