# How to set up ssh so I don't need to input the password each time?

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up SSH so I don’t have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Anyone knows about this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password

Answer (score 5):

This should probably be on superuser ...

This guide discusses setting up ssh keys based authentication: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/.

Basically you create ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2) and populate it with your public key as created by ssh-keygen.  PuTTY for Windows also comes with a key generation tool (and key agent) if you want to automatically log in from Windows.

**Update:** [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password) (It was already there even! :) )

Comment: Another tutorial with screenshots is here: http://wowtutorial.org/tutorial/22.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  `ssh-keygen` to build an SSH key.  Fill in the information, leave the password blank.  The private key was stored in `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and the public key in `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`.  SSH into the server of your choice, and append the contents of your public key file into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.  Create the file and the `.ssh` directory as necessary.

And this question belongs on ServerFault, not SuperUser IMHO.

Comment: It's over there too, heh:  http://serverfault.com/questions/2429/how-do-you-setup-ssh-to-authenticate-using-keys-instead-of-a-username-password

Answer (score 0):

After you use `ssh-keygen` to generate the key see if you have the command `ssh-copy-id` which you use like this

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub remotehost
```

If you don't have `ssh-copy-id` you'll have to log into the remotehost and add the contents of your local `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` to *remotehost*'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`