# automate: finding non-used servers from a list of servers

Tags: linux, top

i posted this on stack overflow but a user recommended i post here.  sorry for cross posting:

0  vote down  star

i have access to a few linux clusters at school. sometimes they are busy and sometimes they are not. i usually log into each machine manually, use the "top" command to see if the server is busy (to see if both cores are used). from there, i execute my program to use some servers that are free to run my computations.

what i'd like to do is to automate this process with a script. suppose i have a list of servers, say server1 ... server N. I'd like to log into each of these servers sequentially, run some command (top?), and output a list of servers that are unused (or output the top two processes, showing cpu %, for each server).

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.  Here is my script for anyone that is interested:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

out=avail.txt
rm -f "$HOME/$out"
minLoad=1
for h in $(cat "$HOME/listofservers.txt"); do
    ##w | head -1 | cut -d : -f 5 - | cut -d "," -f 2 -
    load=`ssh username@$h uptime | cut -d : -f 5 - | cut -d "," -f 2 -`
    comparison=`expr $load \< $minLoad`
    if [ comparison ]; then
        echo "$h" >> "$HOME/$out"
        ##echo "$load" >> "$HOME/$out"
    fi
done
```

PS We do have SGE installed.  However, what I'm doing doesn't play well with SGE yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd look at using w rather than top (returns system load and who is logged in), but look around.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Sun Grid Engine. Or Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Using ssh keys, you can do something like this:

```
for i in server1 server2 server N
 do
       ssh user@$i "uptime" 
 done
```

Uptime command will show the load of the box too. You can use "top -b 1", "w"...

If you need help configuring ssh keys so ssh doesn't ask for password, read here [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)