# OpenSSH without password does not work Cygwin Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, openssh

I've tried several ways to install openssh without password but it does not work. With password it works fine! (Cygwin, Windows7 32Bit)

First I did it like [execute ssh command without password?](https://superuser.com/questions/195299/execute-ssh-command-without-password)

Actually (after completly remove of cygwin, services, users) I did this way:

1. Window 7, no UAC
2. cygwin setup openssh (and mc)
3. Terminal: ssh-host-config
   StrictModes used:               no
   Privilege Seperation:           yes
   Install sshd as service:        yes
   Value of cygwin for the daemon: ntsec
   Registred service "cyg_server"
   create new useraccount
   Password!

   -> host-config finished!
4. Terminal: ssh-user-config
   Create SSH2 RSA identity file:  yes
   Passphrase:                     Empty
   Do you want to use this identity to login to this machine: yes
   (adding to /home/x/.ssh/authorized_keys)

   Same for:
   SSH2 DSA
   SSH2 ECDSA
   SSH1 RSA

   -> Configuration finished!
5. net start sshd
6. ssh x@localhost
   (add localhost to known hosts)

   Conntection closed by ::1
7. ssh x@localhost -vvv

debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/x/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by ::1

What did I wrong? Can please anyone help me?