# Shell scripts on OSX that opens an SSH and Logs in

Tags: unix, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

I'm trying to write a shell script to connect my MBP to my server (for tunneling) every-time it boots. I'm having problem with the password prompt, can you advise?

I found this script online (modified), but spawn and send don't seem to exist?

```
echo "Logging in and creating local proxy"
spawn ssh -2 -R 7654:localhost:7654 -A -D 1080 root@server.com
match_max 100000
# Look for password prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
send -- "\r"
expect eof
echo "All done"
```

Anyone else know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script is solving the problem of the login by giving the pass and login. It is dangereous to write that in a file in any case.
You should better configure your ssh in a way to avoid to give your login pass, you can for example used your ssh keys for that.
Generate your keys on your workstation, ssh-keygen, it will create the keys in ~/.ssh/ the public key is id_rsa.pub. Then in the root account of server.com add your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Answer (score 2):

You should set-up passwordless ssh logins with `ssh-agent`. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password) for a how-to.

Comment: perfect answer.