# How can I store a SSH key on my "terminal session" on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: ssh, terminal, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

I'm using git commands trough SSH over the terminal, but unfortunately each time I try to connect to the server a password is asked. I wish to save that password so that it stops asking.

How can I do that?

I tried to follow [the instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password), but note that I'm using Mac OS X Lion and it seems that it stores the keys somewhere else, or it doesn't load the `ssh-agent` as it should... I've read something about this but I didn't get it.

If anyone has this scenario solved, please be kind to share with us.

Comment: You mean something like this? [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Comment: @slhck: Ups. Guess I've spoken to soon. - MAC OS X Lion (this specif version) seems to not follow those rules. :( So the question still remains, for that specific os X version. I will update my question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Please explain how exactly it does not work.

Comment: @slhck: ArrG!!! It works. I will delete this question, ok ? I did ssh-add inside ~/.ssh (where the keys where stored) I inserted the passphrase all all seems to be fine.

Comment: It would probably be better if we closed it as a duplicate. Helps others when searching.