# Linux + automated login and password with python

Tags: linux

I write the following simple script , the target of the following script is to copy info_file from target Linux (red hat 5.1) machine to my current Linux machine without entering login or password

I will happy to get some work examples with python that perform the same procedure as my expect script

```
  #!/bin/ksh

  rm -rf /root/.ssh/known_hosts

  expect_get_info_file=`cat << EOF
  set timeout -1
  spawn  ssh 100.16.10.15
  expect ?                {send yes\r} 
  expect password:        {send pass123\r}
  expect #                {send "scp -rp 100.16.10.15:/tmp/info_file /tmp\r"}
  expect password:        {send pass123\r}
  expect #                {send exit\r}
  expect eof
  EOF`


  expect -c  "$expect_get_info_file"
```

Comment: Please don't. There are much easier and more [secure ways](http://superuser.com/q/8077/1686) of doing automatic SSH logins than that.

Comment: sorry I dont have expect tool to auto ssh , so the final option is python

Comment: You just completely ignored what I said, didn't you.

Comment: no I am not , I know the ssh and public keys proccess , but I cant use this , sorry ( because some internal ishhues , ) ,

Answer (score 0):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh ....")
child.expect("...")
child.send("...")
```