# How to type on keyboard attached to Windows PC and send keypresses to Linux PC?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, keyboard, kvm-switch, cross-platform

### Context

I want to use a [special keyboard](https://www.infinitytraditional.com/infinity-ergonomic-student/) that only works on a Windows PC (due to drivers). I do all my work on an Ubuntu machine.

The Windows machine and the Linux machine are side by side. They are both connected to a WiFi
router with LAN cables. They both have Bluetooth.

### Question

> Is it possible to type on the keyboard connected to the Windows PC and send the keypresses to the Ubuntu machine?

Would anyone have any ideas for how to do this?

-- ideally, with low latency (i.e. with USB or Bluetooth or direct LAN as opposed to over the internet).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I use a program called synergy for this. It used to be freeware, I think you have to pay a reasonable couple bucks for the new versions.

It allows you to use the second machine as if it was a monitor directly connected. I.e you can have two or three, or more separate machines with their own OS, Mac/Windows/Ubuntu and type, copy and paste text etc between all three seamlessly as if they were all the same OS.

I wouldn't recommend it unless all machines were wired to the same router or switch. Not that it had terrible latency, but in my local wireless environment it was noticable and a little annoying.

https://symless.com/synergy

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a quality USB KVM switch. This will allow using one set of input (and output, if you choose) devices with two physical computers. Check the reviews and manufacturer website before purchasing any KVM switch. This may or may not work due to the driver issue. It shouldn't affect latency at all if the KVM is only passing the connection, and not doing any additional processing on it.

You can do manual switching using Bluetooth, but I find bluetooth switching to be cumbersome. Drivers shouldn't be an issue with a standard bluetooth interface, but keystroke latency over bluetooth might be a problem. I never found a bluetooth keyboard enjoyable to use due to keystroke registration issues.

Without additional hardware purchases, you can remotely log into the Ubuntu machine from the Windows PC with VNC or SSH. This can be configured to work over the LAN. You will not require any internet based solutions.

You can install VNC Server on Ubuntu Desktop with the package manager. You can access that VNC server with a VNC client on Windows. [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/) is a good one. VNC should not be exposed to the internet. This would be my personal preferred solution to work with Ubuntu Desktop. There are other remote agents available other than VNC, but VNC is the most common. VNC latency will be variable, but can be improved if you give up some of the graphical fidelity. There are probably tweaks available in the documentation to improve latency as well.

If you aren't working with Ubuntu desktop, or prefer command line, there are many guides on installing and setting up SSH on this forum and elsewhere on the internet. Here is [one](https://superuser.com/questions/366970/how-to-setup-ssh-key-based-password-less-logins-to-a-linux-macosx-sshd-serv). You can SSH to Ubuntu directly from PowerShell. SSH over a LAN connection shouldn't generate any perceivable latency.

Comment: If you use `ssh -Y ...` you will also be able to start and run GUI software from the shell prompt, e.g. this works nicely on a Ubuntu-based Raspberrry Pie 4 ssh'd from a Ubuntu 20.04.