# SSH key / authorized_keys management tool

Tags: ssh

We have a handful of developers and a dozen servers each with several accounts on them and manage our ssh public keys by manual ssh-copy-id.

Does anyone know of a tool/script to manage ssh authorizations to those hosts?

Some sort of central public-keys list, developer->account@server authorizations and means to deploy those keys with something like ssh-copy-id. I could think of some scripts that would do the job, but would be glad not to do so. And I couldn't find anything except complex Kerberos setups or some ssh.com 'Universal SSH Key Manager' brochure.

Comment: Simple, single user key-management is explained here: http://superuser.com/a/8105/77079

Comment: Sounds like a job for LDAP with all servers authenticating from there.

Comment: I know how to set up SSH to get rid of passwords, but that question shows now way to manage keys / account@server authorizations for more than one server/user... it just shows how to do the login without a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikimedia [uses](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2011/09/19/ever-wondered-how-the-wikimedia-servers-are-configured/) Puppet for this; see their [admins.pp](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=operations/puppet.git;a=blob;f=manifests/admins.pp;h=046b52900f1a9e1a2aac490e1901c0919ac6ac48;hb=HEAD).

Kerberos is actually quite simple to set up.

Answer (score 0):

you may try [secpanel](http://themediahost.de/secpanel/). It has gui support for [managing your keypairs](http://themediahost.de/secpanel/images/keyman.png) and a gui for distributing keys to hosts.