# SSH login without password prompt

Tags: linux, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up SSH so I don’t have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

I am trying to set up Opennebula. I want to set up my local host so that I can log into my remote host without having to use the password.

I have followed the instructions in the "Secure Shell Access" section in the [installation instructions](http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.8:ignc). I can not log into my remote host from my local host, but I can log into my local host from my remote host.

Not sure what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you reversed the SSH key setup. You have to create the key pair on the local host and put the public key into the `authorized_keys` file on the remote host.

Use `ssh -v user@remote_host` to see what happens on the client side. Also check the sshd log (location will vary depending on what distribution you're using, on Debian/Ubuntu it's `/var/log/auth.log`). You may need to increase the log level from `INFO` to `DEBUG` on the server and run `service ssh reload`.

Comment: As described in the installation instructions I have created the key pair in the host and copied the whole folder to the host. But I have also tired copying just the public key to the authorized_keys file on the remote host. Non of the methods worked.

Comment: @user477519 See updated answer. Also you may want to describe how *exactly* the methods "don't work". Do you get any error messages? Which command do you run on which host, and what output do they produce?

Comment: I meant by dont work was, it still asks for a password. I have found the solution for this issue. Please refer to the new answer. Really appreciate your effort. Thanks

Comment: Append the output of `ssh -v user@host` to you question.

Comment: The solution was that the home folder of the user that I try to log into using SSH did not have permissions to read from or to write to its home directory. So after changing the permissions, it worked! I can not post this answer as a solution as it is already marked as closed due to duplication, although other posts did not help me to solve  this issue.

Comment: You're welcome anyway. Glad you got the issue resolved.