# Passwordless connection to GitHub without EVER needing to enter a password

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, github

I cannot figure out how to connect to GitHub from my server (e.g., `git pull`) without ever needing to enter my password. I have followed all the passwordless setup steps as mentioned in [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/8110/39911) and [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), but it requires me to run these steps each time I login:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

It then prompts for my passphrase, adds a id_rsa and id_dsa identity, and then remembers my password for that session. When I re-login, I need to repeat the above steps. I login to my server like `ssh -p xxxx user@server.ip` (passwordless)

When I `git pull` the same repo from my Mac, I am not prompted.

How do I get it to never prompt me from my server?

Comment: I should point out that I'm looking for help for this on my linux / web server (not my Mac). Also, I do not want to use a key without a password.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would use something like [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain) to reattach to an existing `ssh-agent`. I believe there are also other random scripts floating around on the net that perform this function.

An alternative, if you aren't too worried about your key getting stolen, is to generate an SSH key pair *specifically* for GitHub and just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it asks you for a password (thus, the key will have no password on it). In that case, SSH will never prompt you for a password when using that key. (Note: Even if that key does get stolen, the impact would be limited to GitHub.)