# Always being asked for passphrase

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, rsa

I have set up an RSA keypair using

[How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

But I keep getting prompted for the passphrase

> Enter passphrase for key '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa':

It never saves the passphrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh-keygen will ask you to enter a passphrase. At this point, just press enter. Press enter again to confirm the empty passphrase. If you don't specify a passphrase here, you won't be asked for it when you login.

```
# ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): [just press ENTER here to save in the default location]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):                   [just press ENTER here to save your key without a passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again:                                  [just press ENTER here to confirm the empty passphrase]
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
53:4d:b5:72:46:c1:b8:cd:72:82:3e:7a:08:f5:31:e3 user@host
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|            .++. |
|           o.... |
|          ..o++  |
|        ..= +++  |
|       .S+ + +   |
|      .  .E      |
|       . o .     |
|        o .      |
|         .       |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you. So by entering a passphrase you are actually un-doig the usefulness of this (assuming you're doing this to avoid entering a password).