# Password less ssh between two Amazon ec2 instances

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have to install an 12.2 instance for that we need a password less SSH connection between 2 applications nodes. I created the instance using a private key called EC2_linux. I am able ssh to another ec2 instance as ec2-user but I want to connect as user appltest. I tried the following process but it is not working.

1. Server1: ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Server1: copied the id_rsa.pub to server2
3. server2: cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized-keys
   But I am unable to SSH to the server2 as "ssh appltest@server2" without password. How to achieve this setup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](http://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Comment: I tried all the steps mentioned in that link.

Comment: Then you should add this link to your answer and point out which steps are failing.

Comment: How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?

Comment: I followed the steps in above mentioned link and I also set the permissions as mentioned. But still I am unable to login without password.