# Issues setting up SSH to use passphrase

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password) to set up SSH using a public/private key pair, and note just the remote machine password.  I'm guessing the issue is that key pair is for a "different user", but I'm not too familiar with SSH.
Additionally, I'm having difficulty making a keypair "for the correct user" (assuming this is my issue).

I log into the machine with `ssh <official_email>@machine`, where  is some string (associated with the email `<name1>@company.com`).
I have an existing keypair `id_rsa`, and `id_rsa.pub` where `id_rsa.pub` ends with the string `<personal_email>@gmail.com`.
For whatever reason, following the instructions in the linked question don't work (the key file gets copied, which I verified, but I get prompted for the remote machine password each time anyway).
It's my thought the issue is that the keypair I have ends with `<personal_email>@gmail.com`, and I need one that ends with `<official_email>` (probably `@something`, but I'm not entirely sure).

I've tried running `ssh-keygen` and saving it as a new file, but this ends with a file `filename.pub` that ends with `<local_user>@<local_machine>`, which isn't what I want at all.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I on the right track with figuring this out? If so, how can I generate a key-pair that has `<official_email>@machine`?
2. If not, what steps should I take for figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

The end is a comment and won't matter.

The public key should be one line and appended to the authorized_keys file on server you are connecting to, in the ~/.ssh directory of the user ID you're trying to ssh in as.

The .ssh dir itself may need to have have its permissions changed, it should be mode 700

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

The authorized_keys file may need need changing, it should be mode 600

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Generating a new key creates 2 files, a private key (id_rsa if chose rsa default, mode 600) and public key (id_rsa.pub, mode 644) and this public key must be in the destination server authorized_keys file as a single line.