# OpenSSH - PuTTY (Key refused)

Tags: windows, putty, openssh

I'm setting up a small OpenSSH server so that I can access important files without sitting directly in front of my home computer. I've success fully set up the server, but now I want to set up key authentication (so that it's a little bit tougher for someone to break into).

I've copied the keys from my Lubuntu setup, copied them to my windows machine, and converted them to `.ppk` format with **puttygen**. In the `SSH -> Auth` section, I've selected my `RSA.ppk` key file, saved the settings and logged into the server. I enter my username, but then after, I receive the output: `Server refused our key`.

I've uncommented the `HostKey` lines for `RSA`, `ECDSA`, and `ED25519` in my `sshd_config`. I don't know what else I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Please be sure you've gone through all of the steps described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/8110/820).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Answer (score 1):

Using PuTTYgen, I created a randomized public/private key pair, and pasted the text in the output box to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Key file authentication works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

SSH uses two different sets of asymmetric (private/public) keys -- one to authenticate the host/server to the client(s), and optionally a different one to authenticate a client to the host/server.

The `HostKey` configuration in `sshd_config` is for the keys for the host, not for any client. The directive in `sshd_config` that enables pubkey authentication for clients is `PubKeyAuthentication`, but you don't need to specify (or usually uncomment) it because it is on by default.

**It should work**, and does for me, to convert an OpenSSH-generated key with PuTTYgen and use it in PuTTY as you described, but **ONLY** if it is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the appropriate user (*) -- this is required for ANY client key, no matter where or how generated. Generating a key on one Unix system does not automatically add it to `authorized_keys` on that system (since you don't usually need ssh to access a system you are already on) nor any other system (since this system can't know which other systems you might wish to access, including perhaps several years in the future). You mention adding to `authorized_keys` only for your new PuTTYgen-generated key, not the Unix-generated and PuTTYgen-converted one.

(*) or other location if specified by `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `sshd_config` but that's rare