# How to send the password to an SSH login prompt without typing it all the time

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, passwords

Every time I try to connect my Linux server via SSH, it asks me for my password. I’m using Ubuntu server 18.04

How do I do something to get the system to remember the password or just be in line of an Bash script to connect to the server server?

example of what happens to me:

```
ssh root@$ip
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

I did everything to don’t ask me again for password, but I failed.

I’m already using a Bash script like this:

```
echo PASSWORD
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then I copy and paste password into password field. But this doesn’t work.

Comment: Why not use SSH keys? Look at this answer: https://superuser.com/a/8110/167207

Comment: sorry i cant use ssh keys

Comment: i have many ssh servers and i connect them in multiple times , doing that with jeys is too hard

Comment: for the link you send , i recive: 
root@localhost:~# sshpass

Command 'sshpass' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install sshpass

root@localhost:~# apt install sshpass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sshpass

Comment: “i have many ssh servers and i connect them in multiple times , doing that with jeys is too hard.” Makes utterly no sense. I manage dozens of servers and using SSH keys is the simplest way to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: If you need to login without keys but have a password, `sshpass` is the solution. Figure out how to get it installed on your system and you are solid.

Comment: i just compiled https://github.com/bauruine/sshpass un my server , ts okay now , how ever , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use key based login but if you really want to load a password into a script you can do something like create a file in your home folder, change the permissions so only you can read it. This file would have just the password in it, nothing else. Call the file as an example .password.

```
#!/bin/bash
password=$(<.password)
```

The password is now loaded into a variable use that in your script at the point you'll be inputting the password.

But really, use key based login and disable password.

Comment: oh man , i need to enter sopmething then , i need an automated script

Comment: @Aliemaditaj Sorry, we are attempting to help you. But when you say in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1598377/how-to-send-the-password-to-an-ssh-login-prompt-without-typing-it-all-the-time#comment2436070_1598377), “i have many ssh servers and i connect them in multiple times , doing that with jeys is too hard.” that makes utterly no sense whatsoever. If you manage servers the desire is to *always* have SSH keys in place.