# Download files via SFTP non-interactively: how to include password in the command line? I

Tags: command-line, ssh, passwords, sftp

I am trying to to login into a server and download files via SFTP non-interactively: where to place the password in the command line?
Help please! my command is:

sftp  -4rv -b - -o IPQoS=cs1 -o User=user_id -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=yes -o BatchMode=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 @server.com:/ .

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Comment: I am trying to make this command work; According to the Man. Page it should:ftp [-C] [-N name] [-o output] [-s sourceaddr] ftp://[user:password@]host[:port]/file[/] ...Thank you

Comment: FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols. If you use `ftp` like this, your connection won't be encrypted (if the server support FTP at all).

Comment: Thank you Martin, That's why I was trying to use SFTP on the command line :

Comment: not working for me the command line; As I have multiple computers: I am trying : 1-:sftp [-C] [-N name] [-o output] [-s sourceaddr] ftp://[user:password@]host[:port]/file[/.  and 2-sftp -4rv -b - -o IPQoS=cs1 -o User=user_id -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=yes -o BatchMode=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 @server.com:/ .

Comment: OK, I didn't post the best link above. See this one: [Automatically enter SSH password with script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12202587/850848).

Answer (score -1):

Use `sshpass`:

```
$ sshpass -p [pass] sftp user@host:
```

Comment: Please expand your answer with an explanation.